# Convert natural unit to SI unit

Tags: physics, units

Is it possible for MMA to convert natural unit ([particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#.22Natural_units.22_.28particle_physics_and_cosmology.29)), for example,  $1 eV^{-1}$ wavelength, to about $2\times 10^{-7}m$? I think the key is to tell MMA it's a length unit but I don't see how.

Comment: Divide by `hbar*c`. I.e. `q / (Quantity[1, "ReducedPlanckConstant"*"SpeedOfLight"])`

Comment: eV$^{-1}$ is not wavelength, it is inverse energy. But you probably want to convert the energy to the wave-length of photon having such energy.

Comment: It is wavelength in natural units, where $c = \hbar = 1$, and lengths are measured in units of $\text{energy}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few months ago I wrote a function that converts from SI to natural units.  A quick way to achieve the inverse conversion is to convert your target units, meters, to natural units to get about 5e6 1/eV.  Then divide your wavelength in 1/eV by 5.07e6 to get the number of meters.  Of course, it has to work with other units besides 1/eV and meters.

**Conversion from SI to natural units**

Here is a function that takes a SI quantity and converts it to natural units, which are always eV to some power.

```
ClearAll[toNaturalUnits]
toNaturalUnits[q_Quantity] := 
 Block[{α, β, γ, δ, ϕ, χ,
   c2 = Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]^2,
   ℏ = Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"],
   ℏc = Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"] Quantity["SpeedOfLight"], 
   kB = Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"],
   ϵ0 = Quantity["ElectricConstant"]},
  χ = UnitDimensions[q];
  {α, β, γ, δ, ϕ} = \
{FirstCase[χ, {"LengthUnit", α_} -> α],
    FirstCase[χ, {"MassUnit", β_} -> β],
    FirstCase[χ, {"TemperatureUnit", γ_} -> γ],
    FirstCase[χ, {"TimeUnit", δ_} -> δ],
    FirstCase[χ, {"ElectricCurrentUnit", ϕ_} -> ϕ]};
  {α, β, γ, δ, ϕ} = {α, β, γ, δ, ϕ} /. Missing[_] -> 0;
  UnitConvert[
   q  ℏc^(-α + ϕ/2)  ℏ^-δ  c2^(β - ϕ/2)  kB^γ  (4 π ϵ0)^(-ϕ/2) ,
   "Electronvolts"^(-α - δ + β + γ + ϕ)]
  ]
toNaturalUnits[q_List] := Map[toNaturalUnits, q]
```

Here are some common test cases.  In each case, the result should be about 1 eV raised to the appropriate power.

```
{Quantity[389.4 10^12, "Barns"],
    Quantity[0.19733, "Micrometers"],
    Quantity[0.6582, "Femptoseconds"],
    Quantity[1.78266 10^-36, "Kilograms"],
    Quantity[85.43, "Millivolts"],
    Quantity[1519.27, "Terahertz"],
    Quantity[8.12 10^-13, "Newtons"],
    Quantity[432.9, "Volts"/"Millimeters"],
    Quantity[7.318 10^10, "Amperes"/("Meters")^2]} // toNaturalUnits //
   Round[#, 0.001] & // Column
```

**Conversion from natural units to SI units**

This is a rough draft/prototype of a function that takes a quantity `q` and some target SI `unit` and returns a quantity in those SI units.  The first quantity is assumed to be in units of energy to some power.  The second argument is assumed to be a string, like "Meters", or a product of units, like "Newtons"/"Meters".  The second argument of `fromNaturalUnits` will be used as the second argument of the `Quantity` function, so whatever `Quantity` recognizes as a valid unit and is compatible with the first argument should be okay.  Here is the function that converts from natural units to your target units,

```
ClearAll[fromNaturalUnits]

fromNaturalUnits[q_Quantity, unit_] := Block[{
   natTarget, natQ, ratio},
  natTarget = toNaturalUnits[Quantity[1, unit]];
  natQ = toNaturalUnits[q];
  ratio = natQ/natTarget;
  If[TrueQ[QuantityUnit[ratio] == "DimensionlessUnit"],
   Quantity[ratio, unit],
   "error message"]
  ]

fromNaturalUnits[q_?NumericQ, unit_] := Block[{
   natTarget, ratio}, {
   natTarget = toNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, unit]],
   ratio = q/natTarget,
   If[TrueQ[QuantityUnit[ratio] == "DimensionlessUnit"],
    Quantity[ratio, unit],
    "error message"]
   }
  ]
```

Two versions of `fromNaturalUnits` were necessary because sometimes the natural unit is dimensionless.  This function has not be extensively tested, but here is an example of how it works with MMA quantities:

```
m = Quantity["ElectronMass"];
nat = toNaturalUnits[m]
fromNaturalUnits[nat, "Kilograms"]

(*  510998.9 eV
    9.109384*10^-31 kg  *)
```

Here is the speed of light:

```
fromNaturalUnits[1.0, "Meters"/"Seconds"]
(*  2.99792*10^8 m/s  *)
```

Here are conversions from various powers of an eV.  Notice that sometimes `Quantity` will accept abbreviations like `eV` and `MeV`, but not powers of the abbreviations

```
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, ("Electronvolts")^-2], "Barns"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, ("Electronvolts")^-1], "Micrometers"]
fromNaturalUnits[
 Quantity[1.0, ("Electronvolts")^-1], "Femptoseconds"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, "MeV"], "Kilograms"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, "eV"], "Millivolts"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, "Electronvolts"], "Terahertz"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, ("Electronvolts")^2], "Newtons"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, ("Electronvolts")^2], 
 "Volts"/"Millimeters"]
fromNaturalUnits[Quantity[1.0, ("Electronvolts")^3], 
 "Amperes"/("Meters")^2]
```

Finally, what's up with that "error message"?  Well, if the arguments are incompatible, we get the error message.  For example, try to convert 1 eV to seconds.

Comment: In your `fromNaturalUnits` function, what's `target` in the end? I think it should be `unit`.

Comment: @Turgon  Yes!  Good catch.  I corrected the code 2 places.  Many thanks.